# Is disenchanting an item the only way to learn enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I'm trying to learn a rare or powerful enchantment do I just have to be lucky enough to find a weapon or armour piece that has that specific enchantment? Seems like that could be annoying and very time-consuming if I'm trying to learn all of them.

Is there not an equivalent of spell tomes for enchantments, or some other method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Disenchanting an item is the only way to learn the enchantment.

However, the *strength* of the enchantment isn't important. Once you've learned the enchantment, its strength when you apply it to your own gear is determined solely by your own skill/perks. For example, you can learn the *Resist Magic* enchantment either by disenchanting a *Resist Magic +1%* shield or a *Resist Magic +40%* shield -- It doesn't matter which.

If you've got a sweet piece of gear with a strong enchantment that you don't want to destroy, just [keep your eyes open for a weaker/cheaper one](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Generic_Magic_Apparel). Merchants occasionally have enchanted items in stock, so be sure to check them.

Answer (score 3):

Disenchanting is the only way to learn enchantments.

Yes, it is annoying - I am currently at level 40 and have seen no resist frost gear.

Comment: ...and meanwhile my Nord, with her natural 50% frost resist, is finding nothing *but* frost resist gear! Random loot sometimes seems to be conspiring against you...

Comment: Level 41, still no resist shock gear... Of course haven't met a dragon that tried to shock me yet so not too worried