# Skyrim V Elder Scrolls - Enchantment

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been trying to figure out how to learn enchantments.

When i get to the enchantment table I have the item and I have the gems however I do not know any enchantments.

How or where do i learn enchantments?

Comment: [Very closely related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40907/is-disenchanting-an-item-the-only-way-to-learn-enchantments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is disenchanting an item the only way to learn enchantments?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40907/is-disenchanting-an-item-the-only-way-to-learn-enchantments)

Comment: @Wondercricket I'm VTC'ing it as a dupe as the answer there answers both questions

Comment: @Oak I wouldn't quite call them dups in their entirety. While the answers would contain roughly the same information, the questions a different.

Comment: Like I said, the objective answer to this question is already expressely covered in the other question's answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to first find other enchanted items and dis-enchant them to learn the enchantments, but there should be a couple of base enchantments available

Answer (score 0):

In order to learn an enchantment in Skyrim you must have an item that already has an enchantment.

At the enchantment table you'll have the option to to disenchant the item, which destroys the item, but you learn the enchantment which can then be applied to other items.